# javascript: reason for declaring and immedieatly calling inline function

Tags: javascript

So I had an interview where I was asking the purpose of declaring and calling a function immideately, and i couldn't answer it, i.e:

```
(function(){

    // code
})();
```

What's the reason for doing this?

Comment: Encapsulation. Function has it's own scope not visible from the outside.

Comment: Generally its a good practice to avoid polluting the global scope and have all references within the scope of the function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition)**: One good application of immediate (self-invoking) anonymous functions
>   is when you want to have some work done without creating extra global
>   variables. A drawback, of course, is that you cannot execute the same
>   function twice. This makes immediate functions best suited for one-off
>   or initialization tasks.
>
> The syntax may look a little scary at first, but all you do is simply
>   place a function expression inside parentheses followed by another set
>   of parentheses. The second set says "execute now" and is also the
>   place to put any arguments that your anonymous function might accept:

```
(function() {

})();
```

or

```
(function() {

}());
```

are the same: